# Add an integer to UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I would like to add an integer to a `UIActivityViewController`, yet it is not working. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)socialButton:(id)sender {
    NSString *shareText = @"I just scored %i in Helicave!", scoreNumber;
    NSArray *itemsToShare = @[shareText];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Well first off, You wouldn't specify the values of an NSArray the way you have. you would replace it so it would be `NSArray *itemsToShare = shareText,nil;`

Comment: @Coder404 The array in the OP's code is just fine. Your syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
NSString *shareText = @"I just scored %i in Helicave!", scoreNumber;
```

needs to be:

```
NSString *shareText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just scored %i in Helicave!", scoreNumber];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first line,

```
NSString *shareText = @"I just scored %i in Helicave!", scoreNumber;
```

to:

```
NSString *shareText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just scored %i in Helicave!", scoreNumber];
```

You need to tell XCode that the string is going to have formatting, like `%@`, or `%i`, before you create the string